# Sunspot :: "stored => true" doesn't return hits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have set up Sunspot for the first time and it works.  I can search Posts using the following code:

```
Post.search { keywords'some_search_term'}
```

I'm onto the step of implementing highlighting and from the examples I found online I should be able to simply modify my model.rb file to:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title, :stored => true
  end
end
```

I then run the following command to re-index

```
rake sunspot:reindex
```

However it doesn't return any results when I attempt to search again using the same query as above.  So the only code that I add is `:stored => true`.

Is there any other step that I'm missing for Sunspot?  Don't know if this helps but I'm running Rails 3.1.

Thanks in advance!